# Outlook 2010 Search Folder Ignoring Advanced Criteria

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I created a Search Folder in Outlook 2010 to show me everything in my mailbox that isn't in the Inbox or Archive folders. The rules are:

- In Folder is not empty
- In Folder doesn't contain Inbox
- In Folder doesn't contain Archive

[Screenshot: Search Folder Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWH0U.png)

When I open the Search Folder, it shows me all of my e-mails, including those in the Inbox and Archive folders.

[Screenshot: Search folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjwvJ.png)

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In Folder" is not what you really want. What you really want is to create a new custom search folder and select all folders, excluding Inbox and Archive (in "Mail from these folders will be included in this Search Folder").

Comment: I was hoping for a future-proof rule that would explicitly exclude those two folders but include everything else. If I create a new search folder and select a specific set of folders, any new folders that I create will be excluded from the results.

Comment: Yes. But this is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What does "In Folder" mean then, if not the folder that it's in?

Comment: This field is only populated when you're using it as a column for Search Folder's view.

Comment: Ah, I never would have guessed that! Thanks!